# WordPress Custom Post Types Rewrite

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type using WordPress 3.0 that has the following rewrite rule:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'events', 'with_front' => false )
```

which gives the following: domain.com/events/my-awesome-event/

How can I pass some additional info into the rule, such as the date, I'm wanting to have the following rewrite: domain.com/events/2010/my-awesome-event/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Props to [Benj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/378482/benj) in [Using Dates in Custom post_type Permalinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3136518/) - check out this article on [custom post type permalinks](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2)